# PDF Editor For Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I want to create an PDF Editor. Following is my requirement
1- Create a visual force page which can edit PDF lets call it is as an PDFEditor.
2- I am having another VF page called ContractPage which is rendered as PDF.

My functionality is to get all the content of “ContractPage” to PDFEditor where I can change / add or delete the content. And on save this changes should be saved to VF PDF page.

I want to edit content of PDF without using any 3 rd party software.
Thanks,
Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using same controller for both pages and use `renderas="pdf"` in `apex:page` tag of second page. Data entered in first page needs to be captured in controller variables. Then when content is ready you can redirect user to second page to view PDF.